# What is the reason for: error C2512: 'D2D1::ColorF' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013, direct2d

I am upgrading my GDI+ project to Direct2D.
When I rewrote my GDI+ class to Direct2D I got following error message during compilation:
**error C2512: 'D2D1::ColorF' : no appropriate default constructor available**

The header file:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include "d2d1.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "d2d1.lib")

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
if (*ppT)
{
(*ppT)->Release();
*ppT = NULL;
}
}

class Direct3D_Draw
{
HWND mhWnd{};
HDC mHDC{};
PAINTSTRUCT mPS;
HBITMAP bmp{};
HGDIOBJ oldBmp{};

D2D1::ColorF frontcolor;
D2D1::ColorF backcolor;
D2D1::ColorF fontcolor;
D2D1::ColorF fontbackcolor;

public:
Direct3D_Draw(const HWND& hWnd, D2D1::ColorF _backcolor = D2D1::ColorF::White, D2D1::ColorF _frontcolor = D2D1::ColorF::Black);
~Direct3D_Draw();
};
```

The implementation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Direct3D_Draw.h"
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono> //clock_t
//#include <Dwrite.h>
//#pragma comment (lib, "Dwrite.lib")

Direct3D_Draw::Direct3D_Draw(const HWND& hWnd, D2D1::ColorF ibackcolor, D2D1::ColorF ifrontcolor)
{

}

Direct3D_Draw::~Direct3D_Draw()
{
}
```

It is not a full code, just a simplified reproduction. 
Visual Studio 2013 sp5
What is wrong?..

Here the screen of IDE
[image: highkight in IDE]

Comment: Try constructing the member colors in an initializer list in your `Direct3D_Draw`'s constructor. They do not provide a default constructor and require values when your `Direct3D_Draw` class is constructed.

Comment: `What is wrong?`  Doesn't the error tells you what's wrong?  Obviously you can't create `D2D1::ColorRef` objects with no arguments due to that constructor not being available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any class member which is not explicitly initialized in the initializer list of the containing class will be initialized by the default empty (`()`) constructor in any case.

But ColorF doesn't provide a default empty constructor, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd370907(v=vs.85).aspx#constructors), so when the `Direct3D_Draw::Direct3D_Draw()` wants to add the hidden

```
frontcolor = D2D1::ColorF();
...
```

it doesn't find an default constructor for them, you should explicitly initialize them in the constructor, eg:

```
Direct3D_Draw::Direct3D_Draw(....) : frontcolor{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}, ...
```

Comment: Thank you!                     BMPD2DGenerator::BMPD2DGenerator(const HWND& hWnd, D2D1::ColorF _backcolor, D2D1::ColorF _frontcolor):
frontcolor(_frontcolor), fontcolor(_frontcolor),
backcolor(_backcolor), fontbackcolor(_backcolor)
{......